# T-SQL: WHERE Clause - How to adjust based on input variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2008. I have an input param in my stored proc called '@State'. The param can basically be '--All--' or can contain the state to filter.

So, if it is '--All--' I don't want to incorporate the @State into the where clause. Otherwise I'd like it to filter based on the provided @State. So basically it could result in this....

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE Type='AAA' AND Status=@Status
```

or, if they pass '--All--'

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE Type='AAA'
```

How can I do this in a stored proc?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE
    Type='AAA'
    AND Status = CASE @Status WHEN '--All--' THEN Status ELSE @Status END
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought you made a typo. It should be @State, not @Status.  This simple query might not be what you are looking for since you want to two sql statements in your requirement.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE Type='AAA' AND (@State='--All--' or State=@State)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or...

you could make it even simpler than that:

```
 SELECT * FROM MyTable
 WHERE Type='AAA' AND @State in ('--All--', State)
```

No need to do it in a stored procedure, unless absolutely necessary (or if business/coding practice requires you to do so).